# Group by data and find rows with similar values in the each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, duplicates

I am working with a data frame that has 20 ids and for each Id, there are about 3 stores, and each store has a minimum of 3 weekly sales and price elasticities.

Data:

```
data = 
ID      STORE  WEEK_NUM   Price_elasticity          
100001  1      1          0.5
100001  1      2          0.5
100001  1      3          0.5
100001  2      1          0.5
100001  2      2          0.9
100001  2      3          0.6
100002  1      1          0.3
100002  1      2          0.3
100002  1      3          0.3
100002  2      1          0.8
100002  2      2          0.8
100002  2      3          0.5
```

**Problem:**

I would like to find what weeks in each item-loc have the same elasticities

My attempt:

```
dft = data.groupby(['ID','STORE']).agg({'Price_Elasticity':'nunique','WEEK_NUM':'count'})
dft = dft.reset_index()
dft = dft[dft['Price_Elasticity'] <= 1]
dft
```

Expected result :

```
ID      STORE  WEEK_NUM   Price_elasticity          
100001  1      1          0.5
100001  1      2          0.5
100001  1      3          0.5
100002  1      1          0.3
100002  1      2          0.3
100002  1      2          0.3
100002  2      1          0.8
100002  2      2          0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider merging to a value count data frame and return any with count greater than 1:

```py
value_counts_df = (
    df.groupby(["ID", "STORE"])["Price_elasticity"]
      .value_counts()
      .rename("value_count")
      .to_frame()
      .reset_index()
)

df = (
    df.merge(
        value_counts_df,
        on = ["ID", "STORE", "Price_elasticity"]
    ).query("value_count > 1")
    .drop(["value_count"], axis="columns")
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

df
       ID  STORE  WEEK_NUM  Price_elasticity
0  100001      1         1               0.5
1  100001      1         2               0.5
2  100001      1         3               0.5
3  100002      1         1               0.3
4  100002      1         2               0.3
5  100002      1         3               0.3
6  100002      2         1               0.8
7  100002      2         2               0.8
```